# A question about the vertical part of the beam

Tags: homework-and-exercises, torque, statics, structural-beam

[image]

I am solving beam type of problems finding reactions, moments...my question is how do I represent the F2 force that is acting on the vertical part of the beam (on the stick).

Usually there is only a beam on supports, forces in the x and y direction a moment, maybe sometimes an angled force or distributed load, this is the first time I see this kind of problem.

Does the F2 on the stick create a counter clockwise moment or is it just a force acting in the x direction, I need to know so I know in which of the equilibrium equations I put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat it the usual way. Slice the beam and find the force/moment balance.

For example:

[image: FBD]

$$\begin{aligned}
  N - F_2 & = 0 \\
  S + B_y & = 0 \\
  M + x B_y + a F_2 & - 0 
\end{aligned} $$

Then use the $N(x)$, $S(x)$ and $M(x)$ as needed.

Comment: Why the reference to "deflections".? Isn't this a statics problem and not a mechanics of materials problem?

Comment: @BobD - point taken. I edited the answer.

Comment: Your first equation is incorrect. Roller supports like B do not support horizontal loads. That means N has to be zero. And if N=0 your equation says F2 =0, which is obviously incorrect since it is a given horizontal load. I'm not even sure what the second two equations mean.

Comment: @BobD - No it is correct. There is no $B_x$ in the first equation. $F_2$ does transfer through the beam to be reacted by $N$. $N= F_2$ is the _expected_ behavior as the roller support does not alter the loading in the horizontal sense.

Comment: Sure the expected behavior at the roller does not alter the loading in the horizontal 
sense. But as I understand it this is supposed to be a statics problem. The objective is to determine the reactions at the supports. As such the compression of the beam due to the N (the reaction at A) and F2 is irrelevant. All we care about at B is $B_y$ and the moment contribution about B due to F2 as well as the moments contributions about B due to the vertical reaction at A and the couple.  But look, the OP is happy with the answer, so there is no need to debate it further. Sorry if I was a bother.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the F2 on the stick create a counter clockwise moment or is it
>   just a force acting in the x direction, I need to know so I know in
>   which of the equilibrium equations I put it.

Yes, it creates a counter clockwise moment on the beam and it is also a force in the x direction. It's not clear from the drawing what is going on at the left side of the beam, but it looks like the application of a force-couple (pure moment).

In any event, the fact that there is a vertical extension of the beam and a horizontal force on it, does not complicate the problem. Just treat it as another force that contributes a moment.

The problem is actually quite simple, mainly because roller supports cannot support horizontal loads. Consequently, the horizontal reaction at roller B has to be zero. That gives you the horizontal reaction at the pin A. From there, simply set the sum of the moments about A or B equal to zero (not forgetting the moment contribution of $F_2$) to get the vertical reaction at A or B. Then take the sum of the vertical reactions and $F_1$ to get the vertical reaction at the other support.

From here you should be able to proceed independently.

Hope this helps.